# Adding a query string to only one page url

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I would like to add the following to a single page within my wordpress site and NOT all of them.

Current page url/permalink

```
   mysite.com/pagename/
```

Would like to

```
   mysite.com/pagename/?ngg_force_update=1
```

This is so that the nextgen plugin does not use a cached template, as the one i created for it does random stuff on page loads/refresh etc.

And rather than set the values within the actual plugin and have them over written via an plugin update, the url query is the only why, that i know of, but i don't want to add it to all url's etc just that pages permalink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter `page_link` to modify the output of any page's permalink value. The simplest way to identify the page is by ID, then you can append the query string via `add_query_arg`:

```
function wpd_append_query_string( $url, $id ) {
    if( 42 == $id ) {
        $url = add_query_arg( 'ngg_force_update', 1, $url );
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'wpd_append_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks, sorry for the lateness as well.